# Changing the Font of the string attached to the Bindings in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Here is the XAML

```
    <ListView x:Name="duplicateVarsInDepXMLListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="362,360,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Variable Name: {0}'}"/>                       
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value,StringFormat='Value: {0}'}"/>                                               
                </StackPanel>                                           
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This xaml displays a List of collection with Variables Names and the values of a collection. We have something like Foreground property to change the colour of the binding characters or FontWeight to make it Bold.
However i only want to Change the font of the Label e.g. VariableName and not to the actual binding.
Is this possible to achieve? Any suggestions

Comment: What about adding the attribute FontFamily?

Comment: You will have to use two textblocks, one with the "Variable Name:" and other with the actual binding. Then you can change the font of the first textblock.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses the FontFamily will apply to both the binding and the string attached to it. I only want to change the font of the string.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee i want the values to variableName and the binding to appear side by side not line by line

Comment: @sike see gleng's answer, you need to wrap the two textblocks in a panel which orients its child controls horizontally.

Comment: Thanks Victor. Rohit's answer has got the closest workaround. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract out seperate TextBlock and set `FontFamily` on that TextBlock. Wrap both TextBlocks in StackPanel and set the `orientation` to `Horizontal` -

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <TextBlock Text="Variable Name: " FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value,StringFormat='Value: {0}'}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rohit Vats. I'll stick to this one

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Run` elements inside a `TextBlock` and apply different formatting to different runs. You can bind to the [`FontFamily`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontfamily.aspx) property of the `Run` to dynamically set the font:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="Variable Name: " FontFamily="{Binding FontName}"/>
  <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

If the text in the `TextBlock` is wrapped using `TextWrapping="Wrap"` the runs will wrap around as expected. This does not apply to the question but can make using `Run` elements superior to stacking `TextBlock` elements in a `StackPanel`.

Comment: this will apply to both the binding and the string attached to it. I only want to change the font of the string

Comment: @Sike12 - if the declaration is on the `Run` element, then only the text in that run will be affected. This technique has the advantage of keeping the same baseline for all text in the same `TextBlock` so if there are changes in font size or family you won't get "dancing" text and won't need to correct it with margins (as you would need with the "stack panel way").

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal>
  <TextBlock Text="Variable Name: "/>
  <TextBlock Text={Binding Name} FontWeight="Bold"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I want the Variable Name and the Binding to appear in one line not in another line.

Comment: I guess Rohit extended on yours one. Thanks Gleng.